# Search console can't detect structured data after adding through google tags

Tags: seo, google-search-console, tag-manager

Will adding them manually instead of using tag manager help. They all passed the validation test in the Google Structured Data testing tool. I have included two tags. One for implementing products rich card and another a Knowledge Graph Card

Answer (score 1):

Tag manager writes in using the document.write() method.

Googlebot is learning to render a limited amount of Javascript before scraping the page - however, it's extremely sketchy. [Tests have shown](http://www.simoahava.com/seo/dynamically-added-meta-data-indexed-google-crawlers/) that you **can** add in things like  tags or json data using document.write(). However it's so unreliable that it's still better to insert them into the HTML you're sending the client.

Hopefully, some day soon, Google will render Javascript and we can stop using workarounds. Ask this again in a year or two and the answer might be better!